# how to get the user input size(python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the size of the user input and save it in a variable but I can't.  Here is the code

```
senha = input(" insira a senha\n ")
universo = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890")


for i1 in (universo):
    for i2 in (universo):
        for i3 in (universo):
            for i4 in (universo):
                for i5 in (universo):
                    for i6 in (universo):
                        for i7 in (universo):
                            for i8 in (universo):

                                if(len(senha) == 1:
                                    y = (i1)
                                    print(y)
                                    print("senha encontrada")
                                    exit()

                                    if(senha == ):
                                        y = (i1+i2)
                                        print(y)
                                        print("senha encontrada")
                                        exit()
```

I'm a beginner in python so I really don't know how to do that. I try to use the `len()` as you can see but it doesn't work. The second if is empty because I don't know what to put in it to work.

Comment: sorry i forgot to put the variable "senha", here  it is       senha = input(" insira a senha\n ")

Comment: is len(universo[0]) what you need? What should be the output of your program?

Comment: yep i need the len(universo[x]) but its not working. i want that if the input be like one character, just the for i1 works, you get that?, here is the code that doesn't work    
            if(len(universo[1])):
                y = (i1)
                print(y)
                if(y == senha):
                    print("senha encontrada")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like that's what you need:

```
senha = len(input(" insira a senha\n "))

print(senha)

# if user input is "768625", senha is going to be equal to 6 (length of the user input)
```